# Using options in MongoDB\Driver\Query

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I'm trying to use options in MongoDB\Driver\Query:

```
$options = array();
...
if (isset($limit['page']))
    {$options['skip']=($limit['page'] - 1) * $limit['hpp'];}//20
if (isset($limit['hpp']))
    {$options['limit']=$limit['hpp'];//20
    $options['batchSize']=$limit['hpp'];}//20
print('<br />--------$options :<br />');
print_r($options);
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($search, $options);
print('<br />********$query :<br />');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($query);
echo  '</pre>';
```

If $options seems ok:

> --------$options :
>   Array ( [sort] => Array ( [_id] => 1 ) [skip] => 20 [limit] => 20 [batchSize] => 20 )

$query doesn't give me the good options:

```
********$query :  
MongoDB\Driver\Query Object  
(  
[query] => stdClass Object  
    (  
        [$orderby] => stdClass Object  
            (  
                [_id] => 1  
            )  
         [$query] => stdClass Object  
            (  
            )  
     )  
[selector] =>  
[flags] => 0  
[skip] => 20  
[limit] => 0  
[batch_size] => 0  
[readConcern] =>  
)
```

limit and batch_size are not equals to 20, why? and how to do, please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The query object looks very old. Something like v1.0 of the driver. What versions you are using? php, mongodb, and the driver.

Comment: why old? php7, mongodb 1.2.6
driver=?

Comment: The Query should be like `filter=>Object, options=>Object, readConcern=>Object`, see SaschaM78's answer. Your `print_r($query);` returns options on the top level, not within the options object. IIRC it used to be like that a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on PHP 7.2.2:

```
<?php
$options= [
    'skip' => 20,
    'limit' => 20,
    'batchSize' => 20   
];

$filter= [
'_id' => '5a8adcf335f6d112d00e46c8'
];

$query= new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
print_r($query);
```

outputs:

> MongoDB\Driver\Query Object (
>       [filter] => stdClass Object
>           (
>               [_id] => 5a8adcf335f6d112d00e46c8
>           )
>
> ```
>  [options] => stdClass Object
>     (
>         [batchSize] => 20
>         [skip] => 20
>         [limit] => 20
>     )
>
> [readConcern] =>  )
> ```

**Solution (taken from comments)**

The parameters passed as `options` to the Query instance are treated in a type-sensitive manner, in the author's case the parameters were passed from user input and transferred as "string" rather than "number" as excepted. The solution was to use [`intval()`](http://php.net/intval) on the parameters which solved the problem.

**In case things still don't work as expected - update MongoDB**

I checked the changelog of the [MongoDB PECL repo](http://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=mongodb) but couldn't find when the bug was fixed. I would recommend updating to [the most current version](http://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) and test again.

Comment: Thanks, 
well, if I write 
        $options= [
        'skip' => 20,
        'limit' => 20,
        'batchSize' => 20
        ];
It is ok:  [flags] => 0
    [skip] => 20
    [limit] => 20
    [batch_size] => 20 but I don't understand why my first try doesn't work...

Comment: I can only assume that it's due to your variables being initialised from user input (i.e. provided as GET or POST parameters) rather than statically set values. Could you post the output of `var_dump($options);`, after that change your code to use `intval($limit['hpp']);` and try again?

Comment: Thanks, intval() works :)
without it, var_dump gives: array(4) { ["sort"]=> array(1) { ["_id"]=> int(1) } ["skip"]=> int(20) ["limit"]=> string(2) "20" ["batchSize"]=> string(2) "20" }...
strings weren't here my friends.
Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome & great it works! And thanks for accepting! I'll add the final solution to my answer, perhaps somebody else will also fall over this :-).